# Node.js variable retrieval (googl npm package)

Tags: node.js, scope

I'm confused about Node.js its way of handling the variable scope.
I am using a nmp package called [googl](https://github.com/kaimallea/node-googl) for my file. The problem lies in the following code:

```
  var q = text.split(/ (.+)/)[1];
  var googl = require('goo.gl');
  googl.setKey('removed for obvious reasons');
  googl.getKey();
  googl.shorten('q')

  .then(function (shortUrl) {
    console.log(shortUrl);      
  })

  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  });

  return "I minimized " + q + " for you the new URL is: " + shortUrl;
  console.log(shortUrl);
}
```

**I want to retrieve the shortUrl and return it** (returning it inside the .then won't work) **but I am not able to do so**. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the scope of variables here, but that you incorrectly handle asynchronous code. JS will execute lines 1-4 and then line 5, which returns a promise (as the documentation states "Most methods return promises.").

**Then it will immediately execute your `return` statement with an undefined `shortUrl`.**

Then when your promise is resolved you will log the `shortUrl` to the console. But this will be **after** your `return`.

The best thing would be if you returned the promise and used it in the caller like:

```
function foo (text) {
    var q = text.split(/ (.+)/)[1];
    var googl = require('goo.gl');
    googl.setKey('removed for obvious reasons');
    googl.getKey();
    return googl.shorten('q');
}

foo('text').then(function (shortUrl) {
    console.log("I minimized " + q + " for you the new URL is: " + shortUrl);
});
```